# Re: Altsoft Virtocommerce shopify import V2.7

Tags: virtocommerce

I can only import 50 products from shopify. Is there a limit on the number of products able to be imported? Other than that restriction, the extension works well.

Answer (score 0):

We'll fix this issue ASAP and notify you when the extension is available in [VirtoCommerce app store](http://virtocommerce.com/apps/).

Answer (score 0):

New version of Shopify Import module available by this link http://virtocommerce.com/apps/import-from-shopify-to-virtocommerce-platform